# Are cake events handled asynchronously?

Tags: events, cakephp, event-handling, cakephp-2.1

At the moment I don't have any queuing functionality in my Cakephp aplication. I will need that in the near future. An upload will result in a batchjob that uses external API with usage limitations, so it would be best if it was handeled in a seperate threat with a queue.
I don't have any experience with this, so I'm going to try a different, but easier, example.

User actions result in e-mails being send. At the moment, the loading of the page is delayed by the (rather long) time it takes the server to send the e-mail. I'd like to use the Event system to fix this. (I am aware I can also do this using this the afterRender function, or dispatch it to a shellTask, but that way I don't learn anything)

From the example page:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html
I've found this example:

```
// Cart/Model/Order.php
App::uses('CakeEvent', 'Event');
class Order extends AppModel {

    public function place($order) {
        if ($this->save($order)) {
            $this->Cart->remove($order);
            $this->getEventManager()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('Model.Order.afterPlace', $this, array(
                'order' => $order
            )));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Let's say the function was called by a controller action:

```
 public function place_order() {
     $result = $this->Order->place($this->request->data);
     $this->set('result', $result);
 }
```

Now my question... Will the corresponding view be rendered after all the dispatched events completes? or will the Model function just trigger the event and then forget about it? 
The last option seems more logical to me (which also resembles the mentioned jQuery functionality in the article)

The problem is that If this were true, I don't understand the later example:

In the example about using results:

```
// Using the event result
public function place($order) {
    $event = new CakeEvent('Model.Order.beforePlace', $this, array('order' => $order));
    $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);
    if (!empty($event->result['order'])) {
        $order = $event->result['order'];
    }
    if ($this->Order->save($order)) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

if the event was just triggered (and then forgot about) there is no way you can asume it has modified the passed event object on the next line of code!

I would like to use cake as much as possible, but I'm not sure if I can get my desired background behavior without shellTasks and external queue. Any tips about these Cake Events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake Events are triggered synchronously. When an event is triggered, all available listeners are called, before proceeding with other instructions.

You can imagine it on your second example as:

```
public function place($order) {
    $event = new CakeEvent('Model.Order.beforePlace', $this, array('order' => $order));
    $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);  // -> all listeners are called at this point
    // ... here you can assume your $event was modified
    if (!empty($event->result['order'])) {
        $order = $event->result['order'];
    }
    if ($this->Order->save($order)) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thx. You say "if you want".. but it's precisely what I don't want. Can I use them assynchronously? How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that literally. You can't use them asynchronously. You could create your custom event system, or you could dispatch them to a shell.

Comment: Thx. I'm going to solve it with this queueing system: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp_queue for CakePHP